# How to call re-frame.core/dispatch and re-frame.core/subscribe in same event handler

Tags: clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

For example:

```
(defn starrating []
  (reagent/create-class
   {:reagent-render
    (fn []
      [:div
       [:input {:type "checkbox"
                :on-click #(do (re-frame/dispatch
                                [:set-star-rating
                                 (-> % .-target .-checked)])
                               (get-data-from-server))}]])}))

(defn get-data-from-server []
    (let [star (re-frame/subscribe [:star-rating])]
      (ajax/GET (str "http://192.168.0.117:8080/json/searchhotels.json"
                     "?star=" @star)
                {:response-format :json
                 :keywords? true
                 :handler success-handler
                 :error-handler error-handler})))
```

In the above example the checkbox is not set.

When the checkbox is ticked, the star variable is set to true
But after this, when we call subscribe to get the value in star it is returning previous value i.e false

It will call: http://192.168.0.117:8080/json/searchhotels.json?star=false

When you un-check the checkbox, the request becomes
http://192.168.0.117:8080/json/searchhotels.json?star=true

Why re-frame.core/subscribe is returning previous set value?

Answer (score 3):

re-frame has a data cycle: db -> subscriptions -> view -> dispatch events -> db. That's the most important thing to understand here.

- Try setting your checkbox value in `starrating` with a subscription from app-db, so that the data flows from app-db into your view.
- Also try putting `get-data-from-server` inside an event handler, so that your view is not handling all of the mechanics of querying, but rather is just dispatching events, without the knowledge of what needs to happen to respond to them.

There's a bunch of good documentation on this at https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/tree/master/docs

Answer (score 1):

Subscriptions are reactions meant to be use with reagent components.

Dispatch is asynchronous. Use dispatch-sync if you want it synchronous.

Look into https://github.com/Day8/re-frame-http-fx to make ajax calls while keeping your event handlers as pure functions.

Read the docs, re-frame has very good documentation. Readme.md in github. Have a look at example apps in the repository for examples.